# Is it possible to list folders in a google drive folder

Tags: google-drive-api

Using google drive api https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk how can you list folders in a specified folder?
How?

Raster

Comment: Can you provide the information about the sample for Drive API v2 that you have? That may help people think of your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially thought this did not work using v3. Was mistaken. The only criteria seems to be that I use the api to create the nested folder. Than create the folder manually